# Is Astrology considered scientific?

Tags: astrology

It seems that astrological predictions are trials and error method? Can someone please give some examples that make sense? I have seen many people who are trained to read patris make mistakes which are very basic.

Comment: But there are some cases where they do predict the correct answer to certain questions, so that means there is some basis to it. I am just wondering if it the absence of skill to read astrological signs that makes wrong predictions or the method itself is wrong.

Comment: Astrology is perfectly true but I don't know about astrologers who don't know calculations. Entirr cosmos is reflection of Pancha bootha, and same with humans too. He has 5 bodies, 5 koshas etc.. each planet is associated with 1 of pancha bootha and their join separation gives effect based on that. Through Astrology chart a true astrologer can easily get all infos about person's bootha, destiny etc .. at least few % of spiritual evolution one should have to understand and do this. There are so much hidden knowledge. So don't write off anything just based on outer view

Comment: There's Sukshma beyond physical. And it is in communication with outside universe, the 9 vayus -Prana Apana vyana udana dhananjeya etc. .. circulate based on how much energy they get from universe. This is deeper subject which science cannot prove simply because they haven't touched subtle currents and without that they will not know!

Comment: THIRD, Scientific discussions are off topic for the site.!

Comment: we're at a stage where most 'astrologers' did not study jyotisha shastra through traditional methods, and are in it just for the money. jyotisha is true. whether people understand it enough to make right predictions are not, is a case of hit-and-miss. the science is not trial-and-error. the scientists are.

Comment: "Astrology is perfectly true" actually I have seen lots of cases where they are really wrong. Astrologers make wrong predictions about grahas and personalities. It happens all the time. Hashable made a nice comment about this.

Comment: "But there are some cases where they do predict the correct answer to certain questions, so that means there is some basis to it." Sorry I disagree. If a flatearther makes 10 incorrect statements and the 11th is true that doesn't mean the other 10 are correct.

Comment: Is the concept of God scientific? Is the concept of a religion scientific? Can hinduism / christianity / islam be considered scientific?

Comment: How can scientific discussions be off topic if astrology is a science? Are you saying questioning astrology is off topic?

Comment: @TheDestroyer, this is not scientific speculation. this is a discussion of acceptable pramana (pratyaksha vs. shabda), similar to [this](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/34352/is-religion-different-from-science). this must be reopened.

Comment: @AkshayS, this is not scientific speculation. this is a discussion of acceptable pramana (pratyaksha vs. shabda), similar to [this](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/34352/is-religion-different-from-science). this must be reopened.

Comment: @CR241, this is not scientific speculation. this is a discussion of acceptable pramana (pratyaksha vs. shabda), similar to [this](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/34352/is-religion-different-from-science). this must be reopened.

Comment: @TheLittleNaruto, this is not scientific speculation. this is a discussion of acceptable pramana (pratyaksha vs. shabda), similar to [this](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/34352/is-religion-different-from-science). this must be reopened.

Comment: @Aby, this is not scientific speculation. this is a discussion of acceptable pramana (pratyaksha vs. shabda), similar to [this](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/34352/is-religion-different-from-science). this must be reopened.

Comment: Jyotish Vidya is part of Vedic Wisdom. It is between Ngyaan & Vignyan - Between unmanifest & manifest. To shed LIGHT (Jyot) into the HIDDEN (Unmanifest) - PS: Detailed answer/ response in CHAT.